# CSS Animation triggered by JavaScript class add/removes causes site to flash

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

When I remove the class for the first animation, I have a setTimeout(func(), 1) to add the class for the second animation, and in that thousandth of a second the site flashes. But without the setTimeout between class removal and addition the CSS animation won't trigger.

http://codepen.io/nominalaeon/pen/jPbmBx

```
(function ($) {

  var $wrapper = $('.hamburger-wrapper');

  $wrapper.on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);


    if ($this.hasClass('catsup')) {
      $this.removeClass('catsup');
      setTimeout(function () {
        $this.addClass('mustard');
      }, 1);
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('mustard');
      setTimeout(function () {
        $this.addClass('catsup');
      }, 1);
    }


  });

})(jQuery)
```

What up with that

Comment: What browser are you having issues in? I tried it in Chrome and I didn't see a flash.

Comment: In Chrome. The flash happens on the second click

Comment: I've also seen strange behavior from chrome when rendering animations, which includes random text flashing, images disappearing entirely or partially and transformed elements flickering. This seems to be a common issue in Chrome and I doubt it's an issue with your code.

Comment: I see it. Doesn't appear to happen all the time for me, even when I clear the cache.